# glob without GLOB_NOCHECK slowdown

Tags: gcc, glob, slowdown

I have an test main.cpp (not a real project just for testing)

```
#include <glob.h>

int main()
{

  for (int i = 0; i<40000000; ++i) {
    glob_t  gl;
    int ret = glob("main.c", GLOB_NOCHECK|GLOB_NOSORT , 0, &gl);
    globfree(&gl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ g++ main.c
$ time ./a.out
```

Prints:

```
real    0m4.759s
user    0m4.755s
sys     0m0.000s
```

But when I build without **GLOB_NOCHECK** flag, time increases up to 10 times

```
$ time ./a.out
```

Prints:

```
real    0m40.516s
user    0m7.357s
sys     0m33.145s
```

glob function man pages don't contain any information about this issue.

So the question is simple: does anybody know the reason of such behavior?